# Does mehndi change fingerprints? Like for UK visa?

Tags: visas, uk, customs-and-immigration, biometric-passports

I had a marriage in my family just 1 day before UK visa appointment. I gave my fingerprints with mehndi on. Is it going to create problems at airport while biometric? I do not have idea. Please help.